# Hidden material UI still rendering element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to conditionally hide a material ui component.

My first thought was that I'd simply not render the element at all (given I'm not purely hiding it due to 'breakpoint' reasons)... but according to the documentation for the mateiral UI `Hidden` element here: https://material-ui.com/layout/hidden/

> This has the benefit of not rendering any content at all unless the
>   breakpoint is met.

Score, that sounds great.  I could say the `Hidden` element applied when larger than xs and smaller than lg and it'd have the effect of always hiding the component when applied.

However, when I wrap a component in a hidden element using this code:

```
    let withPaper = <Paper>{this.buildQuestion()}</Paper>;

    let withToolTip = withPaper;
    if (tooltip != null) {
        withToolTip = <Tooltip title={tooltip} enterDelay={500} leaveDelay={200}>{withPaper}</Tooltip>
    }

    let withHidden = withToolTip;
    if (this.props.hidden) {
        withHidden = <Hidden xsUp xlDown>{withToolTip}</Hidden>
    }

    return withHidden;
```

only the visibility appears to change.  It still takes up space on the screen.  Look at the following two screenshots. You will notice that the "Station Number" text field shows up when the `Hidden` is not included and it's invisible when it is included... however, the component is still taking up space in the material-ui `Grid`.

(ignore the messed up vertical alignment)
Without the `Hidden` component on the station number:
[image]

With the `Hidden` component:
[image]

Based on the documentation, this doesn't appear to be the normal/correct behavior.

How can I get the wrapped component to completely not impact anything on the screen (hopefully while still being able to access it's values and props?)?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my component was sitting in a grid item (https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/) so, while the Text Field wasn't actually rendering... an empty grid items was.

Comment: Good reminder. I am new-ish to React and this has burned me a couple of times.